# Creating a basic content browsing iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am not new to programming, in fact I have had plenty of experience and know many different languages, but for some reason the Xcode SDK and programming for iPhones really puzzles me. I am trying to create a basic content browsing application, with a list view and detail view you select a topic and then in the detail view details about that topic etc are displayed. Does anyone know of any guides or sample code on how to do this (sample code is best, I can play around with it etc).

I would think one would make use of SQL to store the data, but I am not too sure, I intend to put a fair amount of data in it and merely creating the list items is probably a poor way of doing this.

Comment: Start with the concepts of UINavigationController, UITableViewController - then, when feeling comfortable at that region, start playing with advanced concepts like CoreData.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has a great sample project on their website for using table views (the iOS term for list views) with SQL (called Core Data in iOS). Check out their [Core Data Books](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CoreDataBooks/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008405) example. It was very helpful to me.